# Which feature does linux kernel update that lead to heap not executable on linux 5.10 but executable on linux 5.0 while NX(DEP) disabled

Tags: c, linux, security, kernel, heap-memory

It's a binary compiled by C. I wanted to run some code on heap,but I got a segment fault. Then I use gdb to check the binary. It showed the NX was disabled (complied with `-z execstack` option) and I had RWX access on stack segment while I could only have RW access on heap segment.This happened on a linux 5.10 kernel debian. Then I ran this binary on a linxu 5.10 kernel  Alpine Docker on my Macbook, it happened,too.

I remembered that I could execute code in heap a year before. And I tried to run this binary again on an old Ubuntu18  with  linux 5.0 kernel.  It returned successfully. The codes in stack were executed without error.

In all, my question is if there is any new feature updated from linux 5.0 to linux 5.10 which leads to the heap not executable anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing self-study handout on CS:APP's 4th lab and may get the same problem. Challenge level2 requires to change a global vriable. Most of previous writeups inject some shellcode which executes on the RWX stack, and the stack is actually a heap malloced by programmer. Previous writeups use the buffer to write shellcode and let return address point to shellcode in buffer. However, when I tried the same way on my Ubuntu 22.04 (linux 5.15.0-46-generic) today, a SIGSEGV appeared. The weird thing is that it works on my Archlinux successfully, but that happened in March, 2022. I have no idea if it would work now.

Answer (score 0):

When ELF binaries are linked with the [`execstack` linker option](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html), the permissions for the ELF segment `GNU_STACK` are changed from `RW` (read and write) to `RWE` (read, write, and execute).

When the Linux kernel loads an ELF binary executable, it looks at the GNU_STACK segment to see if the binary wants an executable stack.  See [fs/binfmt_elf.c:load_elf_binary()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c) for details, especially the `executable_stack` variable, and the `EXSTACK_DEFAULT` macro.  Depending on the kernel configuration, it may or may not make the stack executable.

This is an often forgotten backwards compatibility support feature, which can also affect other memory mappings beyond just stacks.  Here is an example program one can compile and run, to verify:

```c
// SPDX-Licence-Identifier: CC0-1.0
// -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef  BUFFER_SIZE
#define  BUFFER_SIZE  128
#endif

#define  PERM_R  1  /* Readable */
#define  PERM_W  2  /* Writable */
#define  PERM_X  4  /* Executable */
#define  PERM_P  8  /* Private */
#define  PERM_S 16  /* Shared */
#define  PERM_RWP  (PERM_R|PERM_W|PERM_P)

struct mapping {
    struct mapping *next;
    void           *addr;
    void           *ends;
    unsigned char   perm;
    char            name[];
};

static inline struct mapping *reverse_mappings(struct mapping *list)
{
    struct mapping  *result = NULL;
    while (list) {
        struct mapping  *curr = list;
        list = list->next;
        curr->next = result;
        result = curr;
    }
    return result;
}

static inline void  free_mappings(struct mapping *list)
{
    while (list) {
        struct mapping  *curr = list;
        list = list->next;
        curr->next = NULL;
        curr->addr = NULL;
        curr->ends = NULL;
        curr->perm = 0;
        curr->name[0] = '\0';
        free(curr);
    }
}

static struct mapping *get_mappings(void)
{
    struct mapping  *list = NULL;
    char            *line = NULL;
    size_t           size = 0;
    FILE            *maps;

    maps = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    if (!maps) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read /proc/self/maps: %s.\n", strerror(saved_errno));
        errno = saved_errno;
        return NULL;
    }

    while (1) {
        struct mapping  *curr;
        unsigned long    addr = 0;
        unsigned long    ends = 0;
        char             perms[8] = { 0 };
        int              nameoff;

        ssize_t  len = getline(&line, &size, maps);
        if (len == -1)
            break;

        if (len < 1)
            continue;
        if (line[len-1] == '\n')
            line[--len] = '\0';

        nameoff = 0;
        if (sscanf(line, "%lx-%lx %7s %*s %*s %*s %n", &addr, &ends, perms, &nameoff) < 3 || nameoff <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot parse /proc/self/maps line: '%s'.\n", line);
            free_mappings(list);
            free(line);
            fclose(maps);
            errno = EIO;
            return NULL;
        }

        size_t  namelen = strlen(line + nameoff);

        curr = malloc(sizeof (struct mapping) + namelen + 1);
        if (!curr) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory parsing /proc/self/maps.\n");
            free_mappings(list);
            free(line);
            fclose(maps);
            errno = ENOMEM;
            return NULL;
        }

        curr->addr = (void *)addr;
        curr->ends = (void *)ends;
        curr->perm = ((strchr(perms, 'r')) ? PERM_R : 0)
                   | ((strchr(perms, 'w')) ? PERM_W : 0)
                   | ((strchr(perms, 'x')) ? PERM_X : 0)
                   | ((strchr(perms, 'p')) ? PERM_P : 0)
                   | ((strchr(perms, 's')) ? PERM_S : 0);

        if (namelen > 0)
            memcpy(curr->name, line + nameoff, namelen);

        curr->name[namelen] = '\0';

        curr->next = list;
        list       = curr;
    }

    free(line);
    line = NULL;
    size = 0;

    if (ferror(maps) || !feof(maps)) {
        fclose(maps);
        free_mappings(list);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading /proc/self/maps.\n");
        errno = EIO;
        return NULL;
    } else
    if (fclose(maps)) {
        free_mappings(list);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing /proc/self/maps.\n");
        errno = EIO;
        return NULL;
    } else
    if (!list) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No mappings listed in /proc/self/maps.\n");
        errno = EIO;
        return NULL;
    }

    return reverse_mappings(list);
}

static inline int  within(const void *const start, const void *const limit, const volatile void *addr)
{
    return ((unsigned long)start <= (unsigned long)addr) && ((unsigned long)addr < (unsigned long)limit);
}

/* Stuff some runtime-dependent data to a volatile buffer. */
static inline unsigned int  stuff(volatile unsigned char *dst, const size_t len)
{
    volatile unsigned char *const end = dst + len;
    unsigned int                  val = 11385419 * (unsigned int)getpid()
                                      + 1792824239 * (unsigned int)time(NULL);
    while (dst < end) {
        *(dst++) = val;
        /* Permute data using Marsaglia; 32-bit XOR Xorshift variant. */
        val ^= val << 13;
        val ^= val >> 17;
        val ^= val << 5;
    }

    return val;
}

static volatile unsigned char  static_global[BUFFER_SIZE];

int main(void)
{
    static volatile unsigned char  static_local[BUFFER_SIZE];
    volatile unsigned char         nonstatic_local[BUFFER_SIZE];

    /* Just stuff runtime data to the three buffers. */
    if (!stuff(static_global, sizeof static_global) ||
        !stuff(static_local, sizeof static_local) ||
        !stuff(nonstatic_local, sizeof nonstatic_local)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Note: We used a bad Xorshift seed.  No harm done.\n");
    }

    /* Do a small (1 KiB) malloc(). */
    void  *small = malloc(1024);
    if (!small) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Note: Failed to allocate 1 KiB.\n");
    }

    /* Do a large (2 MiB) malloc(). */
    void  *large = malloc(2048*1024);
    if (!large) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Note: Failed to allocate 2 MiB.\n");
    }

    /* Do a 64 page anonymous mmap(), without PROT_EXEC. */
    size_t  page = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    void   *enough = mmap(NULL, 64 * page, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (enough == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Note: Failed to acquire a 64-page anonymous read-write memory map.\n");
        enough = NULL;
    }

    struct mapping *maps = get_mappings();
    if (!maps)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    for (struct mapping *curr = maps; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        const char *executable = (curr->perm & PERM_X) ? "executable" : "not executable";
        if (within(curr->addr, curr->ends, &static_global))
            printf("static volatile unsigned char [] in file scope is %s.\n", executable);
        if (within(curr->addr, curr->ends, &static_local))
            printf("static volatile unsigned char [] in main() is %s.\n", executable);
        if (within(curr->addr, curr->ends, &nonstatic_local))
            printf("volatile unsigned char [] in main() is %s.\n", executable);
        if (within(curr->addr, curr->ends, small))
            printf("Small allocations using malloc() are %s.\n", executable);
        if (within(curr->addr, curr->ends, large))
            printf("Large allocations using malloc() are %s.\n", executable);
        if (within(curr->addr, curr->ends, enough))
            printf("Anonymous private PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE memory maps are %s.\n", executable);
    };

    for (struct mapping *curr = maps; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        const char *executable = (curr->perm & PERM_X) ? "executable" : "not executable";
        if (!strcmp(curr->name, "[stack]"))
            printf("Stack (%p..%p) is %s\n", curr->addr, curr->ends, executable);
        else
        if (!strcmp(curr->name, "[heap]"))
            printf("Heap (%p..%p) is %s\n", curr->addr, curr->ends, executable);
        else
        if (curr->name[0] != '/' && (curr->perm & PERM_RWP) == PERM_RWP) {
            printf("%s (%p..%p) is %s\n", (curr->perm & PERM_S) ? "Shared data" : "Data", curr->addr, curr->ends, executable);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you save the above as say `check.c`, you can compile it using for example

```bash
gcc -Wall -O2 -std=c99 check.c -o check.gcc.default
gcc -Wall -O2 -std=c99 -z execstack check.c -o check.gcc.execstack
clang -Wall -O2 -std=c99 check.c -o check.clang.default
clang -Wall -O2 -std=c99 -z execstack check.c -o check.clang.execstack
```

Running an Ubuntu 5.4.0-74-generic kernel on x86-64, the `.default` versions (without execstack linker option) report:

```
static volatile unsigned char [] in file scope is not executable.
static volatile unsigned char [] in main() is not executable.
Small allocations using malloc() are not executable.
Large allocations using malloc() are not executable.
Anonymous private PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE memory maps are not executable.
volatile unsigned char [] in main() is not executable.
Heap (0x1f3a000..0x1f5b000) is not executable
Data (0x7f5e40378000..0x7f5e40579000) is not executable
Data (0x7f5e40794000..0x7f5e40798000) is not executable
Data (0x7f5e40d89000..0x7f5e40d8d000) is not executable
Data (0x7f5e41151000..0x7f5e41155000) is not executable
Data (0x7f5e4117d000..0x7f5e411bd000) is not executable
Data (0x7f5e411bf000..0x7f5e411c0000) is not executable
Stack (0x7ffd124ef000..0x7ffd12510000) is not executable
```

except that because this kernel has address space randomization enabled, the exact addresses above will vary from execution to execution (and this is what we normally want, too); and GCC and Clang tend to use slightly different address ranges, but that too is fine.

As you can see, no data (stack, heap, allocations, or anonymous memory maps without `PROT_EXEC`) is executable.

Running the `.execstack` binaries, however, report:

```
static volatile unsigned char [] in file scope is executable.
static volatile unsigned char [] in main() is executable.
Small allocations using malloc() are executable.
Large allocations using malloc() are executable.
Anonymous private PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE memory maps are executable.
volatile unsigned char [] in main() is executable.
Heap (0xaec000..0xb0d000) is executable
Data (0x7f1f116bd000..0x7f1f118be000) is executable
Data (0x7f1f11ad9000..0x7f1f11add000) is executable
Data (0x7f1f120ce000..0x7f1f120d2000) is executable
Data (0x7f1f12496000..0x7f1f1249a000) is executable
Data (0x7f1f124c2000..0x7f1f12502000) is executable
Data (0x7f1f12504000..0x7f1f12505000) is executable
Stack (0x7ffd5ed68000..0x7ffd5ed89000) is executable
```

This means that the ELF GNU_STACK segment protections are not applied to the stack only, but basically all allocations the process can make.  Even requesting read-write, non-executable anonymous memory, gives the process executable memory.

The question is, does the original asker really see different output running the `.execstack`/`-z execstack` binaries on different kernel versions, or have they fallen foul of Clang's helpfulness?

You see, if you copy one of the many "here's how you can prove you can run code on stack in Linux by default" code snippets which include things like  `volatile unsigned char  injected[] = { 0xf3, 0xc3 };`  (the two bytes being the minimal implementation for a C `void nothing(void) { return; }` function), Clang is helpful and instead of putting `injected[]` on the heap or stack,  it will try and put it in the code section instead.  In other words, when creating such code, one must *always* examine the generated machine code to see where it actually puts the code bytes to be executed, and whether it executes those or just a copy in a code segment.

I admit I was a bit peeved to see the initial claim, because it *looked* very much like someone trying to prove Linux does not default to proper non-executable stack and data regions, by using silly code that does not do what they think they do –– this is what well over half of such code "examples" you find on the internet are: garbage, mistakes, and sheer lies.

However, given the crucial tidbit that all this is related to the `execstack` linker option (implemented for backwards compatibility, so that users who *want* to run programs that only work if they have executable stack, can do so), that changes the question from being related to stack smashing/hacking, into a possible backwards compatibility issue.  We do care about those, you see.

Hopefully, OP will report whether they do really see different output of the above test program on different kernel versions with `execstack` linker option enabled.

If they do, the next step is to pinpoint the change.  It must be later than 5.4.0 (roughly November 2019), and is almost certainly in either [fs/exec.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master/fs/exec.c) or [fs/binfmt_elf.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master/fs/binfmt_elf.c) –– these being links to their modification history.  There are a lot of changes done to these in the last two years, so installing additional kernel versions to bracket the version which introduced the change in behaviour would probably be faster than poring over those changesets.

Comment: Thank you.But This program was compiled with options which enabled execution access of data segments. I compiled your program with `gcc -Wall -O2 -std=c11 run.c -z execstack -o run`, and run `./run 89 f8 f7 d8 c3`. It returned with `Calling stack with argument -1591102874 ... Call succeeded, returning 1591102874.`

Comment: @Ex1t: Ahh!  You are using the `execstack` linker option, intended to help those who have old programs that require executable memory!  You should have said so in your initial post, because that changes *everything*.  I've now rewritten my answer, and it contains a completely different test program.  This one does not try to prove anything; it uses the `/proc/self/maps` pseudofile to examine the access modes the kernel has set for all address ranges used by the current process. [...]

Comment: @Ex1t: [...] Because it does not try to do any shenanigans, but simply asks the kernel, it is suitable as a diagnostic tool for comparing the protections on the kernel mappings provided for an ELF binary executable that uses the `execstack` linker option (which changes the protections on the ELF `GNU_STACK` segment, that the Linux kernel deliberately checks to see what kind of stack that executable wants; however, do note that it is a configurable feature that not many people really need anymore.)

Comment: @Ex1t: Could you please compile (with `-z execstack`) this new test program, and show its output on your newest kernel?  If you can easily boot to an older kernel, knowing whether the output changes (other than exact addresses), would tell us whether it really is a kernel behaviour change, or just a programming bug or optimization or helpful feature that GCC or Clang gained in the mean time.  I admit, I do not believe you have significantly differing output on different kernels, because that would be a pretty big bug breaking backwards compatibility; nevertheless, it may be one, [...]

Comment: [...] and if it is indeed one harming users like yourself relying on this old feature, I think I can help you describe and report it in a way that gets the Linux kernel developers to fix it quick.  (They may be socially abrupt folks, but they do care about this stuff, deeply, so much so as to occasionally berate each other when they cause this sort of bugs and dilly-dally fixing them, because writing new code is more fun than fixing ones own past mistakes.)  It just takes a carefully worded bug report backed with data and an easily replicated test case (the above should do for that).